# Trouble in calling e in method

Tags: java, math

I want to write a Java program which evaluates `e` raised to `-x`.  While calling from `main` what value should I use for `e`?

Comment: Have you looked at the `Math` class?

Comment: Ok you want to write it... So, just go ahead and write it.

Comment: by the way approximate value of e is 2.72...

Comment: When asking questions please provide more context and maybe the code you've tried so far, consult http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for `Math.E` - [javadoc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#E).

Or `Math.exp(double)` which raises the `e` to the power of the `double` - [javadoc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#exp-double-).

Answer (score -1):

The value of e  is approximately 2.718 and has been calculated to 869,894,101 decimal places by Sebastian Wedeniwski . If you are using Java you can declare like this

```
private static final double E = 2.718
```

I hope this is what you were asking .

Comment: You don't need to declare it if you're using Java, it's already there in java.lang.Math, as well as specific functions to calculate e^n and (e^n-1)

Comment: And if you do have a need to define an irrational number as a manifest constant, *surely* you should define it with as much precision as you can.